# Google Maps Api not recognizing package name after Renaming Package name -Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, android-package-managers

I have added Google Maps to my Android Application. When using the API key of my Old package name the map is loading properly.

I renamed the package through Refactor->Rename after this process all the package name in the files has changed, then I created a  API key with the new package name.

```
com.shangeeth.mapstest
```

**changed to**

```
com.shangeeth.simlpemapapp
```

But the Map is not loading with new API key but properly loading with the Old API Key(Old package name API).

Din't I properly Rename the Package name or is there any particular location where I should rename to Load the Map with the new API key.

Comment: Have you tried just requesting a new API? sometimes the API's get locked to specific project names

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project and uninstalling your app and installing it again?

Comment: Renew your api key with new package name.

Comment: You have to update the signature from Google Developer Console. There you can assign an specific Maps API Key to your ApplicationID and signing configuration. Maybe when you refactored the app, this ID has changed.

Comment: I have tried most of these steps but it's not loading with the new API

Comment: Did you receive any kind of error? Are you sure you are using com.shangeeth.simlpemapapp or what you want is com.shangeeth.simplemapapp, try to redo the recommendation process in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps**

-Go to Google API console

-And login with your credentials

-Click the menu expansion button go to credentials menu

-in here you got API key list that you have

-Then you can edit your package name with edit button

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio, go to build.gradle and rename your applicationId in

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.shangeeth.simlpemapapp"
...
```

Also, remember to update package name in AndroidManifest.xml. Hope, this will help. Finally, uninstall your old app from your phone.